# magento adds quotation marks to url

Tags: magento, url, redirect, static, block

I have a static block in Magento that is just an image with a link to a category:

```
<a href="/campaign"><img src="{{media url="..."}}" /></a>
```

When the page loads, Magento has added extra quotations marks around the url, like this:

```
<a href=""/campaign"">
```

Which leads to a 404 error. I have another similar static block with a link to a product, which works ok, though it redirects to another category:

from

```
url: /campaign/subcategory/product
```

to

```
url: /campaign/subcategory2/product
```

I have a regular page with the link written in exactly the same way as in this static block, and that one works perfectly.

There might have been an issue with seemingly duplicate categories when creating it, but there is no conflict as far as I can see now. The category is included in the menustructure, and link works fine there.

Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<a href="{{store url='campaign'}}"><img src="{{media url="..."}}" /></a>
```

Comment: The extra quotation marks are still around the url, unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in the Infortis extension for the rotating banner. In the list of which static blocks should be rotating, there was an extra comma at the end.

Like this:

```
static_block_1, static_block_2,
```

Deleting it made the link work, adding it made the link break again. 
A silly error, which proves that if you can't find your problem in Google, the answer is very simple.